# Bootstrap daterangepicker on button default label

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I've been working with Bootstrap daterangepicker.

My issue is I'm using the button for the datepicker, if we click on that button then datepickerrange should work. Button label should be default value which is given in code. But while using bootstrap daterangepicker, Button label is not displaying instead of that default start and end date is displaying.

My code :

```
<input class="search-select date-range-picker" type="button" value="Datuminterval" />
 $('.date-range-picker').daterangepicker({
              autoApply: true
            });
```

How can I show the button label before I click on it, after I choose the date then it could be fine to show the date from and to.

Your help saves my time. I'm struggling with this issue for past 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

As per below link you should give `start` and `end` date in label, after it will display `default label`
http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4

```
<input class="search-select date-range-picker" type="button" value="Datuminterval" />
 $('.date-range-picker').daterangepicker({
         autoApply: true,
         "startDate": "04/12/2018",
         "endDate": "04/18/2018"
  });
```

`autoApply` just add date automatically when you change date from picker.
Hope it'll work.

Comment: No, in this case too the start and end date only will get displaying. But for me the button name should display first. after the click only the date should show